# Is there any possibility to run dozens of stocks automatically through DCC GARCH (1,1) code?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I found the following code by mister Eric Zivot (https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/econ589multivariateGarch.r).

Could anyone help me, here, in the code, we have only 2 stocks for DCC GACH 1,1 - if I do have, for instance, 100-200 stocks, could I, somehow, run the code to check automatically all possible pairs.

Thanks, 
Markus

Comment: Please make this a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: It's not needed. It's clear in the script.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the code you can see that he used the data "MSFT" and "GSPC".
He calculates the returns

```
MSFT.ret = CalculateReturns(MSFT, method="log")
GSPC.ret = CalculateReturns(GSPC, method="log")
```

creates the combined series

```
MSFT.GSPC.ret = merge(MSFT.ret,GSPC.ret)
```

and fits an univariate GARCH and then the DCC GARCH model

```
# univariate normal GARCH(1,1) for each series
garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), 
                          variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                          model = "sGARCH"), 
                          distribution.model = "norm")

# dcc specification - GARCH(1,1) for conditional correlations
dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(2, garch11.spec) ), 
                           dccOrder = c(1,1), 
                           distribution = "mvnorm")
dcc.garch11.spec

dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = MSFT.GSPC.ret)
```

Here you can change "MSFT" and "GSPC" and if you need help to write for example a loop to iterate over all combinations, post a simple code with your data.frame or matrix with the data and a simple example.

Comment: Thanks Triss, yes, so this guy makes a merged pair of two units, so, for example, I do have AAPL, GOOG, MSFT, MS. So here is 4 stocks, so we can automatically merge all of them by
symbol.vec =c("AAPL","GOOG","MSFT","MS")
e <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbol.vec, from ="2010-01-03", to = "2020-03-19", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
head(pframe)
pframe.ret = CalculateReturns(pframe, method="log")
pframe.ret = pframe.ret[-1,]

but afterwards, do we have any chance to automatically run all pairs through the below code, avoiding copy-pasting of a particular ticker?